# Deactivate User In production, will i be able to deploy changes from Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, user, user-management

I have a Sandbox created by a user George. Let's say i want to make this user inactive in production. Documentation says that i will be able to login to Sandbox with this user, if Sandbox is not refreshed after deactivation. But will i be able to deploy changes that this user deploys to production?
Example:
User George is deactivated in production. I login with this user in Sandbox, do some changes and upload a change set to production. Then i log in to production with another user and deploy changes. Will this be possible or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should be able to deploy the change set in production which is uploaded by inactive user or the user which does not even exists in production.